# Помогите разобраться в ошибках в python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, type-error

В общем, я делаю программку для проекта школьного. Я совсем новичок, буквально только вчера начал писать и совсем не понимаю как исправлять ошибки. Сделал пока путь только Monday>Registration, но после registration окна больше не открываются и выдается множество ошибок. пройдите по кнопкам Monday и Registration - поймёте...

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import json
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile

root = Tk()
root.title("Organaizer")
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.configure(bg='black')
root.geometry('750x600')


#canvas = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400, bg="black", highlightthickness=0)
#canvas.pack()


def mondays():
    monles = Toplevel(root)
    monles.title("MONDAY")
    monles.resizable(0, 0)
    monles.configure(bg='black')
    monles.geometry('750x600')

    def reg1():
        monregles = Toplevel(mondays)
        monregles.title("REGISTRATION")
        monregles.resizable(0, 0)
        monregles.configure(bg='black')
        monregles.geometry('750x600')
    
    #def rl1():
    #   noterl1.pack()

    #def itgs1():
    #   noteitgs1.pack()

    #def maths1():
    #   notemaths1.pack()


    lesson = Frame(monles, width=750, height=600, bg='black')
    lesson.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=1, pady=1)


    registration = Button(lesson, text="Registration", fg='black', bg='white', font=20, width=85, height=6, command=reg1)
    registration.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=S)

    literature = Button(lesson, text="Russian LIterature", fg='black', bg='white', font=20, width=85, height=6)
    literature.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=S)

    itgs = Button(lesson, text="ITGS", fg='black', bg='white', font=20, width=85, height=6)
    itgs.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=S)

    maths = Button(lesson, text="Maths", fg='black', bg='white', font=20, width=85, height=6)
    maths.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=S)

    #notereg1 = Entry(notes, width=375, height=300, bg='white')
    #notereg1.pack()

    #noterl1 = Entry(notes, width=375, height=300, bg='white')
    #notereg1.pack()

    #noteitgs1 = Entry(notes, width=375, height=300, bg='white')
    #notereg1.pack()

    #notemath1 = Entry(notes, width=375, height=300, bg='white')
    #notereg1.pack()




lu = Frame(root, width=250, height=200, bg='white')
lu.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=1, pady=1, sticky=N)

tp = Frame(root, width=250, height=200, bg='white')
tp.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=1, pady=1, sticky=N)

ru = Frame(root, width=250, height=200, bg='white')
ru.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=1, pady=1, sticky=N)

lt = Frame(root, width=250, height=200, bg='white')
lt.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=1, pady=1, sticky=N)

md = Frame(root, width=250, height=200, bg='white')
md.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=1, pady=1, sticky=N)

rt = Frame(root, width=250, height=200, bg='white')
rt.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=1, pady=1, sticky=N)

bt = Frame(root, width=250, height=200, bg='white')
bt.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=1, pady=1, sticky=N)


mday = Button(lu, text="MONDAY", fg='black', bg='white', font=150, width=27, height=10, command=mondays)
mday.pack()

tday = Button(tp, text="TUESDAY", fg='black', bg='white', font=150, width=27, height=10)
tday.pack()

wday = Button(ru, text="WEDNESDAY", fg='black', bg='white', font=150, width=27, height=10)
wday.pack()

thday = Button(lt, text="THURSDAY", fg='black', bg='white', font=150, width=27, height=10)
thday.pack()

fday = Button(md, text="FRIDAY", fg='black', bg='white', font=150, width=27, height=10)
fday.pack()

saday = Button(rt, text="SATURDAY", fg='black', bg='white', font=150, width=27, height=10)
saday.pack()

sday = Button(bt, text="SUNDAY", fg='black', bg='white', font=150, width=27, height=10)
sday.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Вот ошибки:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\evamo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\evamo\Desktop\ff.py", line 26, in reg1
    monregles = Toplevel(mondays)
  File "C:\Users\evamo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2650, in __init__
    BaseWidget.__init__(self, master, 'toplevel', cnf, {}, extra)
  File "C:\Users\evamo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2595, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "C:\Users\evamo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2564, in _setup
    self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот в этой строке не верно вызывается функция:

```
monregles = Toplevel(mondays)
```

Должно быть:

```
monregles = Toplevel(mondays())
```

Comment: Спасибо, ошибок больше нет, но теперь после нажатия на Registration открывается два окна: Monday и Registration, причем первое перекрывает другое. Мне нужно, чтобы открывалось только Registration.

Comment: Я бы на Вашем месте не помещал функции внутрь другой, попробуйте без вложений, будешь проще разобраться в коде и отлаживать. Если ответ подошёл, отметьте пожалуйста как ответ.

Comment: Я даже не знаю что такое функции. И вот эта проблема с открытием двух окон сразу не решена.

Comment: Выражение "def mondays()" - объявление функции, Вы объявляете функцию reg1 внутри другой функции - это не сосем хороший подход для новичка. Советую пройти базовый курс по пайтону, например на степике или на ютубе, что бы понимать основы языка.

Comment: Во-первых, мне это не нужно в долгосрочной перспективе, мне это нужно только для этого проекта, так что я не хочу тратить время на то, что мне не нравится. Во-вторых, я вынес функцию reg за mondays и это не помогло.